# How to extract elements with same tags in the same div in BeautifulSoup using Python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am a beginner learning python through little projects, so currently learning web scraping using BeautifulSoup. The html of the page looks like this :

```
<div class="BrandList"> <div><b>Brand Name: </b>ONCOTRON INJ</div>
 <div><b>Manufacture Name: </b>SUN PHARMA</div> <div><b>Compositions:
 </b>

Mitoxantrone 2mg/ml injection,

</div>
```

I need to parse the information and store it in  a csv with three columns : Name,Manufacture name and compositions.

I tried running my code but i could extract only Brand name, whereas i want the remaining text inside the div.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = requests.get ('http://www.inpharmation.in/Search/BrandList?Type=Manufacturer&ProductID=79').text
soup= BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

brand = soup.find('div', attrs = {'id':'maincontent'})
out_filename = "Sunp.csv"
headers = "brand,Compositions \n"
f = open(out_filename, "w")
f.write(headers)

for BrandList in brand.findAll('div', attrs = {'class':'BrandList'}):
    BrandList['Name'] = Brand_Name.b.text
    BrandList['Compositions'] = Compositions.b.text
    print("brand: " + brand + "\n")
    print("Compositions: " + Compositions + "\n")

    f.write (brand + "," + Compositions + "\n")
f.close()
```

I expected output of Brand name, compositions and manufacture name but i get only brand name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[strip()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip) in-built function of Python is used to remove all the leading and trailing spaces from a string.
[find_all](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) method returns a collection of elements. using `pandas` library to save data into csv file.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

data = requests.get ('http://www.inpharmation.in/Search/BrandList?Type=Manufacturer&ProductID=79').text
soup= BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
brand_list = soup.find_all('div', attrs = {'class':'BrandList'})
brand_json = []

for brand in brand_list:
    my_dict = {}
    brand = brand.find_all("div")
    my_dict['brand_name'] = brand[0].text.split(":")[1].strip()
    my_dict['manufacture'] = brand[1].text.split(":")[1].strip()
    my_dict['compositions'] = brand[2].text.split(":")[1].strip()

    brand_json.append(my_dict)

print(brand_json)
df = pd.DataFrame(brand_json)
#save dataframe into csv file
df.to_csv("sunp.csv")
```